# Hide section when customers go to Product page on wooCommerce

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created Footer in website by make it to section on Elementor and Sticky it on bottom. Now I need to hide it when the customers go to product page or Checkout page in WooCommerce. Where/How can I do it?

I've tried by use css

```
.footer {
  display: none;
}
```

but it's hide on whole website where/how can I add condition?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** - you need to modify the checkout and product templates using `get_footer()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_footer/ where you can create different footers for different templates.

**Solution 2** - just wrapping your code in

```
if(!is_product() || !is_checkout()) { footer code }
```

**Solution 3** - using css you must first check classes in body and do something like

`body.single-product .footer,body.woocommerce-checkout .footer {display:none}`